# Generar número id consecutivo con reinicio anual en PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Da un número de folio e incrementa automáticamente pero quiero que cada año reinicie el Id y cambie el año, que quede así actualmente

> FOLIO-7381/2018

y el otro año inicie así

> FOLIO-0001/2019

```
$ssql="SELECT * FROM edificio
               WHERE edificio_cod_edificio='$codigoedificio'
               ORDER BY edificio_hoja_ruta_ext DESC";
   $rss_consulta = mysql_query($ssql,$conn);
        if($row=mysql_fetch_array($rss_consulta))
        {
                 $hoja_num = $row["edificio_hoja_ruta_ext"];
                 $hoja_ruta_v = $hoja_num + 1;
                 $hoja_ruta_v = $siglaedificio."-".$sigladep."-".$hoja_ruta_v."/".date("Y");
        }

  $fecha_ingreso = date("Y-m-d");
  $hora_ingreso = date("H:i:s");
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer, plero  o me queda totalmente clara en base a que se debe enumerar, en cualquiere caso, esto es lo mismo que pasa con los numeros de facturas que se reinician cada año, esto viene a ser un campo calculado en algunos casos. Necesitas explicar un poco mas en base a que se establece esa numeración  y si es posible facilitar unos datos de ejemplo para aportarte una respuesta.

Comment: Deberias de incluir la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: te comparto el sistema completo para que te des una idea https://drive.google.com/.../14fZ0WQWyZFkuThOF1ARJecGoROa...

Comment: No, no debes compartir tu sistema completo. Contesta lo que se te consulta y agrega la informacion en la pregunta. mira [ask]. ahora cual seria exactamente el problema que estas teniendo? no mantienes una tabla con el ultimo numero?

Comment: el sistema genera un folio automatico ejemplo FOLIO-7662/2018 eso esta bien. pero cuando inicie el siguiente año el folio sera FOLIO-7663/2019, pero yo necesito que sea 0001/2019

Comment: lo que podrias hacer es previamente tomar la fecha actual si es 01-01-2019 la generas y la guardas en tu db, luego como ya guardaste la primera para ls siguientes seria generar +1 es decir ir sumando 1 a cada secuencia cuando se la genere

Comment: Quizás puedes consultar cada día el año y lo comparas con el último registro, si es diferente reinicias el conteo desde cero, sino continua.

Comment: @VakuLuiso Sigues sin aclarar la pregunta, necesitas aclarar en base a que se genera la numeracion del folio, es decir la tabla se llama `edificios` pero no sabemos nada mas que campos tiene, ¿y el numero de folio por que viene dado? ¿que lo determina? ¿por el conjunto de registros de toda la tabla anualmente? ¿por el conjunto de registros para cada edificio anualmente? ¿por la magia? ¿el azar tal vez? Trata de aclarar mas tu pregunta [editandola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/170770/edit)

Comment: buen día, se toma varios datos para generar el numero de folio, edificio_cod_edificio, edificio_hoja_ruta_ext.

Comment: quiero añadir que es un sistema muy complejo por eso decia les comparto el sistema sin problema por que es muy complejo y el codigo esta medio raro. el sistema cuando lo usas es configurable para añadir una o varias empresas de gestion de corresponde asi como es capaz de generar usuarios, perfiles, derivaciones, cargar logos, etc.https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14fZ0WQWyZFkuThOF1ARJecGoROaIx8wE

Comment: Lleva los datos a otra tabla de histórico y trunca la tabla que mencionas, esto reinicializará el índice autoincremental.

Comment: Agrega la fecha de creación del folio a la tabla. Antes de insertar simplemente consulta el año de esa fecha, y si no existe registro reinicias el contador del folio.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que tu tabla contiene un campo 'codigo' y otro 'fecha' para simplificar la respuesta. Asumo, de momento, que creas siempre la nueva orden o registro dentro de su año correspondiente.

Esta consulta te devuelve siempre el siguiente "codigo" de manera correcta, aunque todavía no haya registros para el año actual.

```
(SELECT CONCAT('FOLIO-',LPAD(SUBSTR(codigo,7,11)+1,4,'0'), '/', 
 YEAR(NOW())) AS codigo 
 FROM factura WHERE year(fecha) = YEAR(NOW()) ORDER BY codigo DESC 
 LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT CONCAT('FOLIO-0001', '/', YEAR(NOW())) AS codigo )
ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1;
```

La primera consulta, antes del UNION, busca el código más alto y te lo devuelve sumándole "1" y rellenando con ceros a la izquierda.

Si todavía no hay registros para el año en curso la segunda parte de la consulta viene al rescate y te genera la primera orden o registro del año.

Si necesitas generar registros para años anteriores solo tienes que modificar esta consulta pasándole el año como parámetro en lugar de las expresiones `YEAR(NOW())`.

Yo lo que haría desde PHP sería ejecutar primero esta consulta y con el "codigo" resultante guardaría ya el registro completo. O, mejor incluso, si tienen que rellenar algo en un formulario, ejecutar esto en el script PHP que va a pintar el formulario y dejarlo ya impreso como un "input disabled" en el propio formulario. Luego se enviará con el resto de campos para grabar en la base de datos.

Otra forma de hacerlo sería:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 
CONCAT('FOLIO-',LPAD(SUBSTR(codigo,7,11)+1,4,'0'), '/', YEAR(NOW()))
ELSE 
CONCAT('FOLIO-0001', '/', YEAR(NOW()))
END AS codigo 
FROM factura WHERE year(fecha) = YEAR(NOW()) 
ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1;'
```

Answer (score 1):

creas una tabla que posea el consecutivo y el año asi cuando veas el reporte veras algo asi como año = 2017 folios = 7098 || año = 2018 folios = 20 cada ves que hagas un insert primero has un update aqui en referencia al date("Y"); si el date no existe en la tabla simplemente crea un registro nuevo con valor en folio de 0 y que se guie con eso espero te ayude esta idea